# EF Core 5: How to automatically transform an entity property with a DB function for SELECT & INSERT/UPDATE?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, postgis

Say I have the following entity:

```cs
class Geom {
   public int Id { get; set; }

   public int OwnerId { get; set; }
   public Player Owner { get; set; }

   public string Geometry {get; set;}
}
```

The `Geometry` column isn't actually a string, to get it as a string I need to use a DB function. Similarly, when inserting, I need to use a DB function to transform the string.

**If I wanted to select this from the DB I would:**

```sql
SELECT
  Id,
  OwnerId,
  ST_AsText(Geometry)
FROM
  MyTable
```

**If I wanted to insert it:**

```sql
INSERT INTO MyTable VALUES
    (1, ST_GeomFromText(1 0,2 5,1 0));
```

How do I clue EF Core into the fact that SELECT & INSERT/UPDATE need to use a function to transform the value?

Comment: Why convert to a string? It seems EF Core supports working directly with this data type: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial

Comment: I have limited need to work with the entirety of the .Net Topology Suite. Getting the column back as WKT is good enough for my purposes.